# Use Slash to move foward between date boxes in mui x-date-pickers

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

I have an specific issue using the last version of https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/desktop-date-picker/ Mui x date pickers.

@mui/x-date-pickers

Need to have the same behavior of -> (arrow right key) for slash (/) key.
I mean, If im entering 1 slash 1 slash 1990 should show 01/01/1990, now it's taking me 1/11/0990, because it's not taking the slash as a move-next field box.
This is working using arrow right instead slash. need the same behavior but using slashes.

is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

Have same behavior of arrow right for slash.

Comment: Conversation moved to https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/9595